# Are Mars One sending people on one-way missions to mars, starting in 2024?

Tags: space-flight

The organization, [Mars One](https://www.mars-one.com/)  [claims that](http://www.mars-one.com/#sthash.YxaeEfMW.dpuf):

> Mars One will establish a permanent human settlement on Mars. Crews of four will depart every two years, starting in 2024.

A key part of the success of such a mission seems to rely on the following:

> On Mars, water can be extracted from the soil.

This will supposedly give them everything they need in terms of water, oxygen and food production.

This organization also solicits donations from the public to fund their 'mission to mars'.
That's just ten years from now.

Is this scientifically viable?

Comment: We can't definitively answer questions about what will happen in the future.

Comment: @DJClayworth Maybe I should reword my question better? The organization also solicits donations to help with their project, which might not even be scientifically possible, hence the question.

Comment: Not sure if it would be in the scope of the same question, but one might also be skeptical about whether it's *effectively* impossible due to economics. (Just guessing that "well, if you had a trillion dollars..." might be part of a "scientifically viable" Mars mission.)

Comment: The question seems to be about motivations, beliefs or intentions. Are Mars One people convinced there is a water on the Mars? Do they really plan to send people there, or is it the Mars just a false pretention?

Comment: Not enough of a source, but worth a read in this context : http://www.theverge.com/2014/4/22/5636754/mad-men-in-space-the-ads-that-sold-nasas-golden-age Right now Mars One is primarily a marketing company trying to use the money they earn to start a tech company. Is that reasonable? Who knows, likely to succeed? Probably not.